# Dealing with linkified text in vb.net

Tags: html, vb.net, hyperlink, twitterizer

im dealing with some linkified text using twitterizer.

i get the links in the form of html, so:

```
<a href="LINK HERE">
```

any ideas on how i can just display them as clickable links?

Comment: `ahref` ?  that's not html.

Comment: Looks like HTML with the space missing between `a` and `href`

Comment: thats probably why, they were on seperate lines and i just lumped them together

Comment: Where are you displaying them

Comment: im displaying them in a label

Comment: Also have you seen the big notice on the GitHub repository about twitterizer being depreciated https://github.com/Twitterizer/Twitterizer

Comment: I don't think links are possible in labels, there not meant for user interaction